# Google Charts API: Z-index of data series

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have [following](http://ladariha.cz/tmp/template.html) combined stacked bar with 2 data series: blue and red one. The red one is a single point (of line) and it is by default "invisible" (cover with blue data), you can hover over it, its Y coordinate is about 54 +1 for each day after this question is asked :)

Now the question is, how to make the red dot visible? If I select it, it remains on top, that is exactly what I want by default. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my question, but it is just workaround (working though). After chart is ready, I'm listening to the 'ready' event and immediately select the single point like this

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
    ac.setSelection([{row:0, column:5}]); // use proper values
 });
```